# Logging into zoho remotely using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, zoho

I have a WordPress  site and I have an app of  [zoho](https://support.zoho.com/portal/dataopsinc/signin#home)   , I want to create a new user remotely and login remotely if possible. So that user automatically gets login when i redirect user to zoho.
 I have tried ( one login , mini-orange and others ) but nothing working.